# How to configure mysqli on a compiled php? - compiled with aws lambda php scripting tutorial

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm using [this tutorial from amazon aws](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/) to create an aws Lambda able to run php code. I cannot find many informations about it.

I have this problem now: `Warning: mysqli::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client`. It is quite common and answers to locate the `.ini` file. But i don't have any because my php is compiled and stored in a single directory.

Stats:

- `php 7 bin`
- compiled/configured with `--with-mysqli` and the [php mysqli installation manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) says it will include standard `mysqlnd` driver, which idk if needs to be further configured or replaced with another driver.

I'm looking for a way to configure my mysqli to solve this problem, and maybe if you also had this experience and you know what errors i'll have, consider sharing your solution to us. I and the whole internet will thank you.

### Edit 1

i've ben asked, so i write it here: with *compiled php* i mean that i followed the instructions from aws, taking the source code and `make install`ed it.

### Edit 2

I found with `phpinfo();` (thanks [IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop)) that my `php.ini` file is expected to be found in the path where all have been compiled, but i'll move everything into an aws lambda, so i need to tell php to look elsewhere. but how?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by PHP being "compiled" - maybe just that it's a _custom_ build, not the "normal" one you'd install elsewhere? Regardless, if you look at the output of [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/phpinfo) it will tell you what configuration files it read, or tried to read, on startup, as well all its current configuration. You can also set _some_ settings at runtime; I would imagine mysqli-related ones would be in that category, but since you don't mention any particular settings, I can't be more specific.

Comment: hi, thanks, i used `phpinfo()` and it provides a lot of information. i found a couple of interesting things: charset seems to be utf8, that's not standard anymore, as i red elsewhere i will edit it when i'll found `php.ini`. But it's more important that the `php.ini` file seems to be expected where the source code has been compiled, not where it is now.